# In Ubuntu 17.10 key combinations like Ctrl + Shift + Alt + ... don't work

Tags: shortcut-keys

I upgraded Ubuntu to 17.10 and found out that alt key has strange behavior.
If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, for example, I can see the menu of the active window, but If I press more complicated combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>some_letter</kbd>, it doesn't react. In Ubuntu 17.04 it worked.

The only way of solving this problem I know is to use *gnome-tweak-tool*. In this *gnome-tweak-tool*, I can swap key Win (Super) with key Alt. In this case everything works great, but... I would like key Win to be key Win and key Alt to be key Alt. So, may be there is a good solution for this problem?

Comment: Some people use Caps lock for changing the input language. Possibly, using Caps lock is better workaround then that I mentioned in my question (one key instead of two), but it is still not the best solution

Answer (score 13):

There's an simple workaround [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1683383/comments/32):

> In case you don't need to switch between keyboard layouts, you can get
>   some shortcuts working again if you use the "Tweaks" tool for Gnome.
>
> ```
> sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
> ```
>
> Then
>
> 1. Open "Tweaks"
> 2. Select the tab "Keyboard & Mouse"
> 3. Click "Additional Layout Options"
> 4. Disable entries in the "Switching to another layout" dialog
>
> In my case this gave me back the "ALT + SHIFT" combinations which are
>   essential in the Eclipse IDE for refactoring.

[image: screenshot]

It works beautifully!

Comment: Mostly correct, but you still can use a shortcut to switch keyboard layouts. You just need to create different shortcut. For example I use Super + Space

Comment: Kudos to you man!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this problem using the patch [from this ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1683383).
But the latest supported version is 1.19.3 while actual is 1.19.5 so this also requires some changes in patch/shell script to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you override ctrl, so you need to install Tweak Tools and to return ctrl's position.

1. `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Then some magic

   - Launch Tweaks
   - Select "Keyboard & Mouse"
   - Select "Additional layout options"
   - Change "Ctrl Position" (in my case it was *at bottom left*)